# Undesired delay at beginning an Acitivity

Tags: android, bitmap, imagebutton

I am working with some Acitivitys , it's working pretty well. But i am having a strange delay on it.

And I figure it out that, it was about this part of the code, where I am loading stored image in the SDCard.

```
    if(p.getAdress() != null){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p.getAdress()); 
            new_image.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            new_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Why this simple code is taking too long to execute?

How to solve it?

If I take this code off, everything works as i wished.

Comment: Is it a very large bitmap? Either way, you could load this in an AsyncTask to prevent the delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't load large bitmaps directly on the UI thread.

Actually, the best reference to loading large Bitmaps efficiently can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

And right [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) you can find good information on how you can load them using an AsyncTask.

This is the method they show you there (you can even [download the sample](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip)!)

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}



 public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance, I am new at Android, never seen this (Integer... params) , I am reading the Google leasons, but it's so complicated, too many new things, all I want is to show the photo in a ImageButton... is that the simpler way to do that?

Comment: (Integer...params) is actually more of a Java kind of thing. It means that there can be several parameters, all of Integer type. And the main point is that: a.) there's an example that can guide you along as you learn and b.) in Android you shouldn't be doing heavy processing in the main thread but, for instance, in AsyncTasks.

Comment: Thank you DigCamara I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your can try this way. It help you

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  if(p.getAdress() != null){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p.getAdress()); 
            new_image.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            new_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

                return "Executed";
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
          }

          @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
          }
    }
```